# MySQL querying date range

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my database (free rooms in a hotel, simplified)

**rooms_available**:

```
id  date_available   room_id
================================
1   2013-12-19       2
2   2013-12-20       2
3   2013-12-21       2
4   2013-12-22       2
5   2013-12-23       2
6   2013-12-25       3
```

**rooms**:

```
id  name           minimal_range
================================
2   Apartment A    5
3   Apartment B    1
```

I want to query all rooms which are available between 2013-12-20 and 2013-12-22

My query is like:

```
select * 
from rooms_available 
where (date='2013-12-20' OR date='2013-12-21' OR date='2013-12-22')
```

My questions:

- is there a more comfortable way? when the date range will be like 2 weeks, the query will also be very long (which will take much longer for querying)
- would it be possible to consider minimum ranges - for example: room_id 2 is only available for at least 5 nights (see table "rooms") -> so above query should return no records

Thanks

Comment: I suspect that it's more common to store when the rooms are taken rather than when they're available

Comment: This question is asked about 100 times on SO, so you might want to check already answered question next time

Answer (score 1):

date >= '2013-12-20' and date <= '2013-12-22'

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM rooms_available WHERE `date_available` BETWEEN "2013-12-20 " AND "2012-03-31"
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this but it should point you in the right direction especially for the second part of your question about minimal range.

```
SELECT t1.id as id, t1.date_available as date_available, t1.room_id 
FROM rooms_availble as t1 JOIN rooms as t2 on t1.room_id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.date_available BETWEEN DATE('2013-12-20') AND DATE('2012-03-31') AND
t2.minimal_range <= datediff('2013-12-22', '2012-12-20');
```

The mysql [datediff](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/196414) function will return the number of days between two dates then you can just compare it with the minimal_range from the rooms join table. Also you might consider binding the start and end dates to variables so that you only have to write each date once.